# nodejs use REQUEST.get, callback never called

Tags: node.js, express, oauth-2.0, request, wechat

I am using [request module](https://github.com/request/request):

```
request.get({
     url: 'https://www.google.com'        
}, function (err, response, body) {
    console.log('callback called!' );
```

I opened the request debug mode:

```
require('request').debug = true;
```

so i saw the debug output:

```
   REQUEST { method: 'GET',
  callback: [Function],
  url: 'https://www.google.com' }
REQUEST make request https://www.google.com/
```

but the callback was never called

so, what's the problem? Is it relate to https?

Comment: Is the destination server perhaps looking for a header that your browser is sending (e.g. `User-Agent`)?

Comment: hi @mscdex , i edited the post, seems it not relate to destination server.

Comment: Does it work with plain http? You could try using wireshark/tcpdump to verify that no data is being received by the server, but I suspect something may be blocking the traffic?

Comment: @mscdex I tried, it not even work with plain http using the request sample code.

Comment: Which version of request? You've mysteriously tagged this question with oauth 2.0 and wechat, that makes me think there's more to your code than you're showing. Can you show us more? Preferably a minimal but complete code sample that reproduces your problem.